# Is parking in Paris free in August?

Tags: budget, automobiles, paris

I was planning a trip to Paris and I just noticed that parking in August is free. Unfortunately the place where I read it only mentions 2014. A quick google search always points to 2014.

Is parking in Paris free in August?
If so, is it free everywhere (all streets, public parking lots)? is there a place to check this?
Is it free for all kind of vehicles?

Comment: Don't park anything on the street that you don't mind getting a few scrapes. "Bump to park" is common.

Comment: @pnuts You should write that as an answer

Comment: @pnuts I also saw some additional information ranked lower from 2015, but since than things may have changed back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pnuts pointed out in the comments:

> PARIS city hall has voted to stop offering free parking throughout the
>   month of August.
>
> Only drivers with a disabled badge or the owners of an eco-friendly
>   vehicle will still be able to benefit from the perk, which has been a
>   long tradition in the capital when it is deserted for summer holidays.<sup>[Source](http://www.connexionfrance.com/end-of-free-paris-parking-in-august-17147-view-article.html)</sup>